# Is there any way to convert more than one python file to a program?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

So, I have written a lil program in python.
It consists of a main.py, a utils.py (with all my functions), a requirements.txt and a folder named resources with two .txt files in which the scripts save lists.
Now is my problem: I wanted to convert the files using a) pyinstaller and then b) auto-py-to-exe, but none of these worked for me!

Everytime, a .exe came out which executed only the first parts of the main.py. But as soon as the program needs to access e.g. the utils.py, the exe crashes.
I added all the necessary files by using --add-data (which the program fills out by itself).
What can I do or what did I do wrong?

- pyinstaller
- auto-py-to-exe
- adding additional files using --add-data

Comment: Please show us the full error message.

Comment: @Xukrao The problem is, that the .exe doesnt show any error message, it just terminates the process.

Comment: Did you start the executable using the command prompt?

Comment: @Xukrao No, I started it by double-clicking the main.exe.
But I could solve the first problem. All the named files are being recognized, but I get an error as soon as colorama (module) is being used. I also tried adding it w/ a requirements.txt, but that didnt work also.

Comment: Then try starting the executable from the command prompt. This should prevent the error message from disappearing immediately upon program crash. Also ensure that you're NOT using any of the the following options: -w, --windowed, --noconsole

Comment: Also for this new error the advice applies: please show us the full error message.

Comment: @Xukrao My bad! But anyways, after a quick re-convert, everything worked... Sometimes, auto-py-to-exe shows up some dumb errors... Quick fix.
Nevertheless thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was:

- using auto-py-to-exe
- adding my .txt files AND the folder with it as their destination path
- re-converting the files
- opening w/ the terminal instead of the .exe

Now, everything works as it should be!

Comment: it should still work from the file explorer though, its not a big deal now probably, but if you can't run apps for the file explorer no one will use it, because most people won't go through the trouble of using cd to get to the folder and then opening it

Comment: @EbrahimMomin Sorry, I forgot to mention that. Sure, that works too! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try pyinstaller --onefile file1.py file2.py
file1 and file2 being main and utils, and you can add more files as well